# 14.04, Gnome Hang

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome

Approximately every hour or so, the GUI on my fresh 14.04 / NVidia Binary / Dell laptop hangs.

Bailing out to console and have a look at syslog, the last entry is:
apcid: client 1146[0:0] has disconnected.

immediately returning to graphics session results in a functional display, with screen corruption that can be restored with min/max of current window, which usually is Firefox.

I haven't had much opportunity to see if this affects things outside of Firefox, or if firefox may be the cause of such problems.

Update:  does not appear to be linked to firefox
session is still accepting input (display isn't refreshing), when returning from console screen has updated to reflect activity while unresponsive (changing application though touch screen, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a graphic card issue to me. To start off with, type `lspci | grep VGA` and take a note of your Graphic card model, just to make sure it is NVidia.

To install the unofficial drivers for NVidia, follow these steps :

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and login with your user name and password. Execute the following commands, one by one :

`sudo killall -9 gdm`

`sudo killall -9 Xorg`

`sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current`

`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -y install nvidia-current`

This will update your current Nvidia drivers and hence solve the problem you're facing .
Good luck!

Comment: definitely nvidia.

Already appears to be using the most current released version of the nvidia driver; according the what is available at the PPA. I don't disagree that its a problem with the nvidia driver... but I think its a maybe a lower level problem.  Thanks for help.